# How do I control a BLDC with greater precision using bluetooth?

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, bluetooth, electronics, drone

I am building a quadcopter drone and I have 4 BLDC motors that I can control using an HM10 Bluetooth module and the "Dabble" application.
My problem is that when I use a virtual joystick in the "gamepad" module of the Dabble application to control the speed of the motors, it seems to be limited to 2 or 3 speeds. The joystick module that I am using is supposed to have values of 0 to 7 depending on the distance of the joystick from its center. Yet the motor only moves once the joystick is halfway away from center, and then it only spins at a couple different speeds when I push the joystick further. Here is my code:

```
#include <Servo.h> //Servo library
#include <Dabble.h> //Dabble library for bluetooth connection

#define INCLUDE_GAMEPAD_MODULE //Includes Dabble Gamepad module
#define CUSTOM_SETTINGS


Servo ESC1; //define the 4 motors
Servo ESC2;
Servo ESC3;
Servo ESC4;

int Speed; //create a variable for speed of motors

void setup() {
  Dabble.begin(9600); //Set the baud rate for the HM10 to 9600
  ESC1.attach(9); //Set the motors to their corresponding pins on the arduino
  ESC2.attach(10);
  ESC3.attach(11);
  ESC4.attach(12);
}

void loop() {
  Dabble.processInput(); //Refresh information from the Dabble application
  Speed = GamePad.getRadius(); //Get a value from the Dabble application corresponding to the distance  of the joystick from center (0 to 7)
  Speed = map(Speed, 0, 7, 0, 180); //translate the value from the Dabble application (0 to 7) into the "language" of the motors (0 to 180)
  
  ESC1.write(Speed); //Set the motors to the new speed
  ESC2.write(Speed);
  ESC3.write(Speed);
  ESC4.write(Speed);
}
```

Comment: Can you check what values the Dabble application actually sends? That might show us on which side the problem is.

Comment: that sounds like a good idea but I am not too sure how to go about that. The dabble app is on my phone and I cannot have my laptop connected to the arduino while this is running as apparently it will fry the USB port

Comment: Update: I'm silly, I can simply unplug the motor and then read the data while connected to my laptop. Turns out the arduino is receiving all values 0 through 7 as intended. The problem must be with the BLDC somehow.